# Edge distribution points evenly distributed on circle

Tags: probability

We have a circle of radius R on which we evenly spread points. We are interested in the distribution of points by radius and polar angle that you get after transforming the even distribution of $f_X(x, y) = 1/\pi R^2$,
from cartesian coordinates (x, y) to polar coordinates (r, φ) and specify the edge distributions sought. Check if the edge distributions are normalized.

I do not want solution the the problem, beacause i know that this is agains the policy on this platform, but i want hints how to tacle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the area made by increasing the radius from $r$ to  $r+dr$.  The number of points will be in proportion to the area.

Comment: What does $f_X(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi R^2}$ actually represent here.

Answer (score 0):

If your points are evenly spread around a circle, they are separated by an angle of $360^o$/N, where N is the number of points. Choose a starting point, and if needed, convert from polar to Cartesian coordinates.  If you want the points spread over the area within the circle, it is a much more complex problem. Do you want them at the corners of squares or triangles, and then, how do you deal with the curved boundaries? Do you require symmetry?